Why does system GMM fail due to computationally singular system in my setup?
I am estimating a system of seemingly unrelated regressions (SUR) with gmm::sysGmm in R. Each of the equations has one unique regressor and one common regressor. The common regressor is a dummy indicating the last observation. I impose a restriction that the coefficients on the common regressor are equal across equations. The fitting routine yields the following error:
Error in solve.default(w, t(hm)) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 3.35459e-19

This happens only for certain types of the covariance matrix estimator: MDS and HAC. It does not happen for CondHom. Also, I am able to estimate the model without a problem using restricted OLS estimation via systemfit::systemfit. I think the latter estimator is algebraically the same as gmm::sysGmm with identity weighting matrix and the CondHom option for the error covariance matrix. This suggests the problem is with estimating the error covariance matrix when allowing for heteroskedasticity of errors. What exactly is this problem?
I can understand there would be an issue if I did not the impose cross-equation restrictions of equality of the coefficients on the common regressor. Then the last error of each equation would be estimated as exactly zero, and that would upset the estimation routines under heteroskedasticity of errors. Also, if such an estimator were used in the first stage of the GMM, it would cause trouble there. However, with the identity weighting matrix in GMM, I do not expect it to be used in the first stage.
Question: Why does system GMM fail with an error of a computationally singular system in my setup? What could I do to fix this?
library(gmm)

# Generate and prepare the data
n <- 100 # sample size
m <- 1   # length of the "second part" of the sample
N <- 3   # number of equations
set.seed(321); x <- matrix(rnorm(n*N),ncol=N); colnames(x) <- paste0("x",1:N) # generate regressors
dummy <- c( rep(0,n-m), rep(1,m) ) # generate a common regressor
x <- cbind(x,dummy)                # include the common regressor with the rest of the regressors
set.seed(123); y <- matrix(rnorm(n*N),ncol=N); colnames(y) <- paste0("y",1:N) # a placeholder for dependent variables
for(i in 1:N){
 y[,i] <- i + sqrt(i)*x[,i] - i*dummy + y[,i]*15*sqrt(i)   
 # y[,i] is a linear function of x[,i] and dummy, 
 # plus an error term with equation-specific variance
}
data1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(y,x)) # create a data frame of all data (y and x)

# Create the model equations and moment conditions
ES_g = eqSystem_h <- list() 
for(i in 1:N){
 ES_g[[i]] <- as.formula(assign(paste0("eq",i), value=paste0("y",i," ~ x",i," + dummy"))) # define linear equations of SUR
 ES_h[[i]] <- as.formula(assign(paste0("eq",i), value=paste0(       "~ x",i," + dummy"))) # define the moment conditions for GMM
}

# Estimate the model with `sysGmm` using different weighting matrices: identity, "optimal" and manually specified
m1 <- sysGmm(g=ES_g, h=ES_h, wmatrix="ident", vcov="MDS"    , crossEquConst=3, data=data1) # Error: system is computationally singular
m1 <- sysGmm(g=ES_g, h=ES_h, wmatrix="ident", vcov="HAC"    , crossEquConst=3, data=data1) # Error: system is computationally singular
m1 <- sysGmm(g=ES_g, h=ES_h, wmatrix="ident", vcov="CondHom", crossEquConst=3, data=data1) # Just fine
summary(m1)

 Related: 
* System GMM yields identical results for any weighting matrix 
* SUR estimated via systemfit vs sysGmm: different standard errors 

Just a guess at HAC: something like this can happen as in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/139614/robust-ols-standard-errors-newey-west/139617#139617 so maybe (!!) the way residuals are (not) weighted in HAC causes problems.

The main reason is that your moment matrix is badly conditioned. This is specific to your dataset. Using momentfit, we can try to see what happens if we compute the moment matrix using one case that works (vcov="CondHom")
## We get the estimate using gmm
m1 <- sysGmm(g=ES_g, h=ES_h, vcov="CondHom", crossEquConst=3, data=data1)
## We create a system object for momentfit
smod <- sysMomentModel(g=ES_g, h=ES_h, data=data1, vcov="MDS")
## We organize theta to be used by the momentfit methods
theta <- coef(m1)
names(theta) <- smod@eqnNames
## We then compute the moment matrix:
gt <- evalMoment(smod, theta) ## This is a list of moment matrices                                                                                                                            
gt <- do.call("cbind", gt) ## convert the list into a matrix                                                                                                                                  
qr(gt)$rank ## Should be full rank, it is not (7 instead of 9)                                                                                                                                

In the case of "MDS", the weighting matrix is $W=[\sum_{i=1}^n (g_ig_i')/n]^{-1}$, where $g_i$ is the $i^\mathrm{th}$ row of the moment matrix. For the inverse to exist, the moment matrix must be full column rank.

Thank you! I have little experience with GMM, so could you perhaps elaborate in more layman terms? What do you mean by "this is specific to the dataset"? I have tried changing the random seed, but that does not help. Is the problem rather in the data generating process or the model specification (or the pairing of the two)? What should be tweaked to make the "MDS" and "HAC" options work?

Setting m=10 does not throw an error message, which indeed speaks to the hypothesis that, with m=1, a column of almost only zeros leads to near-singularities

Could the problem stem from the first step of the estimation? If equation-by-equation OLS is used there, then we get some zero residuals, and they cause problems when estimating the variance for these data points.
